# Flask form TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am trying to make a registration form with flask. My code seems clean with all the proper data types indicated. The error also gives emphasis to `if form.validate_on_submit():` found in my `routes.py`. I am now lost and I dont really know what to do.

Edit: I need it to successfully POST the data. Please help me.

**Routes:**

```
from flask import render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
from registration import main
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from registration.models import Student, Colleges

@main.route("/")
def index():
    return redirect(url_for('register'))
@main.route("/register", methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    form.college.choices = [(c.id, c.college) for c in Colleges.query.all()]

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        college = Colleges.query.filter_by(college=form.college.data).first()
        reg_student = Student(student_number=form.student_number.data,last_name=form.last_name.data,first_name=form.first_name.data,college=college.id,section=form.section.data,email=form.email.data)
        db.session.add(reg_student)
        db.session.commit()

    return render_template('register.html', form=form)

@main.route("/admin")
def admin():
    return "Students list"
```

**Models:**

```
from registration import db

class Colleges(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    college = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    students = db.relationship('Student', backref='department', lazy=True)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"College('{self.college}')"

class Student(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    student_number = db.Column(db.String(11), unique=True,nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    college_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('colleges.id'), nullable=False)
    section = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Student('{self.student_number}','{self.last_name}','{self.first_name}','{self.college_id}','{self.section}','{self.email}')"
```

**Forms:**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField, IntegerField, SelectField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo


class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    student_number = IntegerField('Student Number', validators=[DataRequired(),Length(min=11,max=11)])
    last_name = StringField('Last Name',validators=[DataRequired()])
    first_name = StringField('First Name',validators=[DataRequired()])
    college = SelectField('College', coerce=int,validators=[DataRequired()])
    section = StringField('Section', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')
```

**register.html:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
<form method="POST">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Register:</legend>
    {{ form.student_number.label }}
    {{ form.student_number(class="form-control form-control-lg") }} 

    {{ form.last_name.label }}
    {{ form.last_name(class="form-control form-control-lg") }} 

    {{ form.first_name.label }}
    {{ form.first_name(class="form-control form-control-lg") }} 

    {{ form.college.label }}
    {{ form.college(class="form-control form-control-lg") }} 


    {{ form.section.label }}
    {{ form.section(class="form-control form-control-lg") }} 

    {{ form.email.label }}
    {{ form.email(class="form-control form-control-lg") }} 

    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}

  </fieldset>

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3):

I still haven't tried using Flask. Please do correct me if I'm wrong.
I think the problem lies on this line under RegistrationForm() class:

```
student_number = IntegerField('Student Number', validators=[DataRequired(),Length(min=11,max=11)])
```

Upon checking [WTForms Documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/validators.html#built-in-validators), wtforms.validators.Length() validates a string yet you're using this validator on IntegerField(). Try using StringField() instead.

Comment: Changed it and apparently it still doesnt work. Although in the server log it says POST

Answer (score 0):

For `IntegerField()`, use `NumberRange()` instead of `Length()`.

https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/validators/?highlight=numberrange#wtforms.validators.NumberRange

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34575282)